# should I use ANTLR to transform simple SQL select statements?

Tags: sql, antlr

I need to write a program that accepts a basic SQL select statement and outputs an XML file which breaks down the statement into it's component parts (the output columns, the input tables, the join, group by, aggregations, etc.). At a minimum I need to support 2 tables in the from statement, different join types, where clause, group by and having. If more complex sql can be supported (e.g. subqueries) that's a bonus, but not necessary.

I checked out ANTLR and it looks like a steep learning curve. Given that I have the ability to require the SQL to be fairly simple, should I attempt to hand code or should I embark on the world of ANTLR?

Comment: "It depends." While I am not saying "use ANTRL", as there are other alternatives (I like a recursive-descent or parser-combinator approach), using proper parsing techniques is the only way to properly handle even a relatively tiny subset of SQL. Of course, if "it works" then "it works" and life goes on... on the other hand, maybe someone already has an ANTLR-based project that parses the required SQL :)

Comment: What about using an existing SQL parser?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you want to optimize your query, you should look at your databases's EXPLAIN PLAN. Or are you trying to build your own SQL engine?

Comment: If you are aware of some code for another approach and can refer me to it that would be great. Same goes for an existing parser that I can leverage. That would be great. but it needs to be something I can modify/play with to meet my needs.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish: not a sql engine but for my home-brew etl tool. I need to be able to record each join, filter, group by etc that needs to be taken. The etl tool with output this  meta-data as SQL with proper logging and error checking. I already have a gui for drag and drop to get what I need. But I'd like to create an alternate approach for someone who knows SQL to do it faster. They could type the SQL, the program would parse it into the metadata steps for the ETL tool. Long-story short: I don't want to reinvent the wheel on parsing SQL if I can help it.

Comment: Well, there are tons of existing SQL parsers (but I don't know with what language you're working). Just stuff the key words  `sql parser LANGUAGE` (where `LANGUAGE` is the programming language you're using) in your favorite search engine.

Comment: I would recommend learning ANTLR, regardless of whether you use it for your immediate requirement. Knocking together a simple (i.e. limited) SQL implementation with ANTLR would not be a lot of work and also sounds like a great way to learn ANTLR. As @Bart says, they may be a library out there that does exactly what you want. YMMV

Comment: There are already several sql grammars available at http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list that might get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to reinvent such a sql parser with ANTLR. Here is a sample that decode select SQL statement into meta-data:

```
SELECT e.last_name      AS name,
   e.commission_pct comm,
   e.salary * 12    "Annual Salary"
FROM   scott.employees AS e
WHERE  e.salary > 1000
ORDER  BY
  e.first_name,
  e.last_name;
```

Meta info:

```
            Select statement:
                Select set type: none

            select clause:
                Columns
                    Fullname:e.last_name
                    Prefix:e    Column:last_name    alias:name
                    Fullname:e.commission_pct
                    Prefix:e    Column:commission_pct   alias:comm
                    Fullname:e.salary * 12
                    Prefix: Column:e.salary * 12    alias:"Annual Salary"

            from clause:
                scott.employees as e
                tableowner: scott
                tablename:  employees
                tablealias: e

            where clause:
                e.salary > 1000

            order by clause:
                e.first_name,
            e.last_name
```

If this is what you need, then you can check [this article](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/decoding-sql-grammar-select-statement/) that illustrate how to use a [sql parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Steep learning curve of ANTLR consists mostly of learning recursive descent parsing technique. The syntax and the idiosyncrasies of the tool contribute to the complexity, but they are secondary. In other words, you would need to learn how to do parsers no matter what, but with the checks built into automatic parser generator you minimize your chances of coding an invalid grammar.

You could also opt for a pre-built SQL parser ([here is one for .NET](http://software.topcoder.com/catalog/c_component.jsp?comp=24311277) and [another one for Java](http://software.topcoder.com/catalog/c_component.jsp?comp=10023914)). I tried them both, and they work fine. You may need TopCoder membership to download the components. Both these components use generated parsers, but they use JavaCC and its C# port instead of ANTLR. The grammars are reasonably close, though, so you may choose them as a starting point for your project.

Comment: great solutions but unfortunately the site which hosts them (top coder), so far as I can tell, gives me no information about what the cost would be to use one of these solutions for commercial use.

Comment: @snowguy I do not know anything about their pricing, because I never used their components for commercial projects, but I don't think it's too high, because their costs are very low. I'm sure they would be happy to send you pricing info by e-mail. If the price does not suit your needs, however, you can always use the projects as inspiration for your own work: free downloads include full sources.